# Is there any way to emulate bad blocks?

Tags: io, emulation, block

We want to test how our software will deal with HDD bad blocks. Is there any way to emulate bad blocks on HDD? Is there any software in which i can mark several blocks as bad blocks?

I know, in oldest time, there was a software in norton commander, where user can mark blocks as a bad block - is there any tool, which can work with filesystems and mark blocks as bad blocks?

Comment: you can generate bad blocks reversibly on linux, and likely any software that implements the `write-bad-sector-[test]` flag

Answer (score 0):

If you mark blocks as bad, OS will not use it and so bad blocks  will not affect your software. Probably, you need unchecked bad blocks